# How can I add custom admin theme in custom admin module

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I've created new admin module. And now need to create new admin template for this newly created custom module. This template should be totally different from already existing layout,css and image. I have create to overrite an existing admin module but could not able to create a new layout and design for newly created custom module. Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have to add this to your module's config.xml as < config > tag child:

```
<stores>
  <admin>
    <design>
      <theme>
        <default>yourthemename</default>
      </theme>
    </design>
  </admin>
</stores>
```

then you can use design/adminhtml/default/yourthemename/{layout, template} folders for your admin theme.

I'm not certain about skin folder but it's possible that the above configuration also enables you to use skin/adminhtml/default/yourthemename folder for your css and image files.

Comment: I have applied this code in my custom_module admin config.xml but the theme changes for all modules in admin.